# cp multiple files do not work in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I would like to run the below command in a bash script but, it doesn't work.

command:

```
cp /tmp/first/{abc.conf,xyz.conf} /tmp/backup/
```

bash script:

```
firstDir=/tmp/first
#secondDir=/tmp/second
validDir=$firstDir
#validDir=$secondDir
backupDir=/tmp/backup

files='{abc.conf,xyz.conf}'

join=$firstDir/$files
#join=$secondDir/$files

cp $join $backupDir
exit 0
rm -rf $validDir
mkdir $validDir

cp ("$backupDir/*.conf") $validDir
```

error:

```
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/first/{abc.conf,xyz.conf}': No such file or directory
```

The objective is to clean the directory and then put back only those 2 files.

Comment: IIRC, brace expansion takes place before parameter expansion (e. g. variables), which is why this is not working as you expect.  For an operation this simple, you might be best served just running two individual `cp` commands for the two files you wish to preserve.

Answer (score 3):

[Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) happens *before* parameters are expanded, so

```
files='{abc.conf,xyz.conf}'
join=$firstDir/$files
```

results in literally setting the variable to `/tmp/first/{abc.conf,xyz.conf}`, and it won't be re-processed when it's expanded in your `cp` command.

Instead, you could write

```
cp "$firstDir"/{abc.conf,xyz.conf} "$backupDir"
```

literally, and it will expand the way you want.

There is no way to force brace expansion to happen out of a variable, but you could use an array to keep the filenames and command separate, even using brace expansion to define it:

```
files=( "$firstDir"/{abc.conf,xyz.conf} )
```

and later `${files[@]}`.

Comment: That works great! Cheers!

Here is the code:

    firstDir=/tmp/first
    secondDir=/tmp/second
    
    if true; then
            validDir=$firstDir
    else
            validDir=$secondDir
    fi
    
    backupDir=/tmp/backup
    
    files=( "$validDir"/{abc.conf,xyz.conf} )
    
    cp ${files[@]} $backupDir
    
    rm -rf $validDir
    mkdir $validDir
    
    cp "$backupDir"/{abc.conf,xyz.conf} $validDir